# Spring + CDI + JPA + Tomcat 7 (JDK7) + Hibernate not inserting on mysql

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, cdi

I'm trying to use CDI with Spring and JPA (hibernate), but i'm having some problems.

Imovel (Entity)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Imovel")
public class Imovel implements Serializable, BaseEntity{}
```

ImovelBean

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class ImovelBean implements Serializable {

@Inject
private ImovelDao imovelDao;
}
```

ImovelDao

```
public class ImovelDao implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private EntityManager manager;

@Inject
public ImovelDao(EntityManager manager) {
    this.manager = manager;
}

public Session getSession() {
    return (Session) manager.unwrap(Session.class);
}

public void insert(Imovel imovel) {

    getSession().save(imovel);

}
}
```

When I try to insert:

Hibernate logging:

insert 
    into
        Imovel
        (bairro, cep, cidade, complemento, endereco, estado, numero, observacao, quarto, tipoImovel, tipoSituacao, tipoVenda, valor) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

But my entity isn't persisted on database.

Using List it worked:

```
 Criteria cri = getSession().createCriteria(Imovel.class)
            .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("tipoSituacao", TipoSituacao.Ativo));
```

I'm using persistence.xml, web.xml, beans.xml, context.xml and applicationContext.xml. If need more information, please!

Comment: Why aren't you simply using the entity manager, why on earth are you unwrapping to the session?. Just do `manager.persist` instead of the ugly hack you are using. You don't seem to have anything transaction related in your code, no transaction, no commit, no persistency...

Comment: @m-deinum I tried to use manager.persist but it doesn't work. No log errors too. I some parts i wanna use hibernate session, like criteria stuff. So, I think its not related with JPA or Hibernate.

Comment: where are you starting a transaction? are you using CDI (Weld) or Spring?

Comment: @JohnAment which file would u like inspect? I post it...

Comment: JPA has the Criteria builder which is similar to the criteria API from hibernate. If you want to use criteria still then just use the session in that place don't use it every where as it just adds complexity. As I also stated in my initial comment **You don't seem to have anything transaction related in your code, no transaction, no commit, no persistency**

Comment: @M.Deinum why find using works and persist don't? I really in doubt.

Comment: For reading you don't need a transaction, for persisting (making it last) you do. Also when doing a persist and then a find the entity will be retrieved from the first level cache directly instead of the database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Spring and Tomcat, but I don't think it's a problem. I'll try to describe design solutions what I use.

I always make my DAO `@Named` and use `@Inject` when I want to inject some DAO to service layer. Also, I use `@PersistenceContext` annotation when I want to inject `EntityManager` to my DAO. Then, in DAO i just do `entityManager.persist(entity)` when i want to insert into table, or `entityManager.find(YourEntity.class)` when I want to `SELECT * FROM ...`. (Also I use `GenericDAO` pattern, but it's not necessary)

I don't know how Spring works with transactions, but I suspect something like `@Transactional` annotation in your service methods, don't forget about it.

UPDATE: Could you show your `persistence.xml`?

Comment: I tried this but didn't work. The fact that I see a query doesn't mean that the data is actually COMMITTED to the database. I think my problem is with inject transaction.

Comment: Also you should set logging level to `DEBUG` and see logs, it may contain useful information.

Comment: That's strange. What will be the result if you make SELECT then INSERT then SELECT again (through entity manager)? Empty tables on both SELECT? I mean, do `entitymanager.find` then `entitymanager.persist` then `entitymanager.find`.

Comment: Yes! If I persist some date directly on mysql, em.find works! It means that not related with database and connection is ok.

Comment: It is related to your transaction as I mentioned in the other comments the find reads from the first level cache directly. It will NOT be in the database.

Comment: @gustavomr if so, I agree with M. Deinum about transactions. You can't do anything in your database without transactions.

Comment: @Everv0id any tutorial how to do this with JPA and CDI?

Comment: You should do it on service layer, not in your DAO beans. In EJB there is a `@TransactionAttribute` annotation which is used to configure transactions. In Spring there is a `@Transactional` annotation, but I don't know much about it, you should google it yourself.

Comment: its about transaction. I don't know but my entity manager is not working with it. When using 
  this.manager.getTransaction().begin();
  this.manager.persist(arquivo);
  this.manager.getTransaction().commit(); it worked!

Comment: As I said, you shouldn't do it on DAO layer. DAO layer has to provide only atomic operations with database, and transactions should be a part of your business logic.